# Webpack ..how to find or require bundle.js files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

I recently had ensues with Webpack as I don't quite understand it and I need it for react and redux get working. 
I successfully run webpack but I don't find the bundles .
I tried to use CommonsChunkPlugin() but nothing happens.

here is the    webpack.config.js :

```
let path = require('path');
let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./public/brain/main.brain.js",
        index:"./public/brain/index.brain.js",
        login: "./public/brain/login.brain.js",
        register:"./public/brain/register.brain.js"

    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"js"),
        filename: "[name].nerve.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "bundle",
            chunks: ["main","index", "login","register"]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "nerve-users",
            chunks: ["login", "register"]
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "nerve-index",
            chunks: ["index"]
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react' ,'env']
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

[Cmd:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTbzJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the config suggests, your bundles will be saved inside a folder called 'js' with the following names:

- main.nerve.js
- index.nerve.js
- login.nerve.js
- register.nerve.js

Comment: Not there..there are no nerve.js files ,but thanks for help .

Comment: Looking at your configuration, I don't think you'd need to use the CommonsChunkPlugin at the moment. Try to comment them out and see if you get some change. Also, look at the console and see where your bundle is saved (`reasons: true` inside `stats`)